# Would like to loadtest my website

Tags: vps, benchmark

I intend to host my site on a VPS and before I do, I wanted to test to see how much ram/cpu it will require for given number of concurrent users. What is the best way to set up a VPS on a home mahine with spcific CPU and RAM allocated to it so that I can test my site in it? Should I use Virtualbox? Or are there better alternatives for acomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Siege to do load testing.
http://www.joedog.org/

Comment: I was thinking about Jmeter, although it does not really matter which I use at this time. What I am inquiring about however is how exactly can I simulate a VPS (virtul private server) I need to test to see how much concurent users my site can handle under 514 ram, then 1 gb ram, etc...

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is a decent way of doing this.  In my opinion, it's the most "polished" of the free virtualization options.  VMWare Server is another option, though in my opinion the quality of it has gone drastically downhill since they switched to the web interface.

Comment: Would I be able to allocate set amount of RAM/CPU in virtualbox? how accurate is that?

Comment: Virtualbox will limit the memory/cpu to the values you specify.  It's not really any different then using any other virtualization software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [analysis and related tools](http://journal.uggedal.com/tags/vps). He's published the [source code](https://github.com/uggedal/vpsbench) as well!